# Let $B$ be a root of $x^6 +30x^5 - 15 x ^3 + 6x -120. $ What is $[\mathbb Q(B):\mathbb Q]$? What does the elements of $\mathbb Q(B)$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know we are looking for the dimension of this and that the dimension is highest power of the irreducible polynomial. I am confused about how to find this value for $B$.  I also think the form is like $x = A_1 +A_2\sqrt{2}+...$ but I also am not sure how to relate this to $B$.

Comment: Can you show that $x^6 +30x^5 - 15 x ^3 + 6x -120$ is irreducible?  *Hint*: Eisenstein.

Comment: Yes I believe we can

Comment: You probably know that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ when $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$